# My all data are not getting stored in Coredata

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data

I'm fetching values from Server and storing them to Coredata.The issue is coming that when i fetch data from server and store them in coredata, it shows that i have stored my values all values.....

These are my data which are been stored:

```
  [{
    adName = Britannia;
    adType = Video;
    addescription = "Choco Muffills come with thick chocolate filling that will take you by surprise.";
    clientImage = "http://api.weoneapp.com:8595/1464528609370.png";
    clientName = Britannia;
    endDate = "Just now";
    entryId = 1478230186228;
    likeFlag = 0;
    mainImage = "";
    newAdvertisement = 1;
    noOfCount = 1367;
    noOfLike = 2783;
    seenAdvertisement = 0;
    smilURL = "http://52.66.101.222:1935/vod/_definst_/1478230186228/smil:1478230186228.smil/playlist.m3u8";
    sortDate = "2016-11-03T19:27:00.000Z";
    startDate = "2016-11-03T19:27:00.000Z";
    subTitle = "Britannia Cake Muffills";
    thumbNail = "http://52.66.101.222:8595/video/1478230186228/1478230186228_thumbnail.png";
    videoDownloadUrl = "http://52.66.101.222:8595/video/1478230186228/1478230186228_source.mp4";
}, {
    adName = "Kwality Walls";
    adType = Video;
    addescription = "Paddle Pop Yummy Delicious Dessert - A delicious, colourful and yummy dessert ... Walls India \U00b7 Kulfeez from Kwality Walls India \U00b7";
    clientImage = "http://api.weoneapp.com:8595/1464524885184.jpg";
    clientName = "Kwality Walls";
    endDate = "Just now";
    entryId = 1478230623594;
    likeFlag = 0;
    mainImage = "";
    newAdvertisement = 1;
    noOfCount = 1281;
    noOfLike = 2618;
    seenAdvertisement = 0;
    smilURL = "http://52.66.101.222:1935/vod/_definst_/1478230623594/smil:1478230623594.smil/playlist.m3u8";
    sortDate = "2016-11-03T18:36:00.000Z";
    startDate = "2016-11-03T18:36:00.000Z";
    subTitle = "Paddle Pop Jiggly Jelly";
    thumbNail = "http://52.66.101.222:8595/video/1478230623594/1478230623594_thumbnail.png";
    videoDownloadUrl = "http://52.66.101.222:8595/video/1478230623594/1478230623594_source.mp4";
}, {
    adName = "Cadbury Dairy Milk";
    adType = Video;
    addescription = "Your favourite chocolate is now more chocolatey.";
    clientImage = "http://api.weoneapp.com:8595/1464017173884.jpg";
    clientName = Cadbury;
    endDate = "Just now";
    entryId = 1478230473291;
    likeFlag = 0;
    mainImage = "";
    newAdvertisement = 0;
    noOfCount = 1310;
    noOfLike = 2600;
    seenAdvertisement = 1;
    smilURL = "http://52.66.101.222:1935/vod/_definst_/1478230473291/smil:1478230473291.smil/playlist.m3u8";
    sortDate = "2016-11-03T18:32:00.000Z";
    startDate = "2016-11-03T18:32:00.000Z";
    subTitle = "Cadbury Dairy Milk";
    thumbNail = "http://52.66.101.222:8595/video/1478230473291/1478230473291_thumbnail.png";
    videoDownloadUrl = "http://52.66.101.222:8595/video/1478230473291/1478230473291_source.mp4";
}]
```

Now when i go to my .sqlite folder, which is at this location : */Users/Johnn/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0DF66BFE-6076-45E9-8325-D61F1C738DFA/data/Containers/Data/Application/DC3F7B17-1172-4AE3-BC3B-217624C21AA5/Documents/AppCoreData.sqlite*

and open this .sqlite file> Go to my table i found: 
[image]

that only two values are stored my last value of entry is empty.

I don't know what's the reason behind this,why my last value of array is not getting stored in database...

I am storing the values like this:

```
    class func createInManagedObjectContext(nameOfAdvert: String, thumbnail: String, fileName: String, videoDownloadUrl: String, subTitle: String, adType: String, mainImage: String, noOfLike: NSNumber, entryId: String, likeFlag: Bool, startDate: String, endDate: String, noOfCount: NSNumber ,clientName: String, clientImage: String, adDesc: String, sortDate: String, newAdvertisement: Bool, seenAdvertisement: Bool) -> Tube {

    let managedObjectContext = DataAccess.shared.managedObjectContext

    let newItems = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Tube", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Tube

    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()

        newItems.adName = nameOfAdvert
        newItems.thumbNail = thumbnail
        newItems.smilURL = fileName
        newItems.videoDownloadUrl = videoDownloadUrl
        newItems.subTitle = subTitle
        newItems.adType = adType
        newItems.mainImage = mainImage
        newItems.noOfLike = noOfLike
        newItems.entryId = entryId
        newItems.likeFlag = likeFlag
        newItems.startDate = startDate
        newItems.endDate = endDate
        newItems.noOfCount = noOfCount
        newItems.clientImage = clientImage
        newItems.clientName = clientName
        newItems.addescription = adDesc
        newItems.sortDate = sortDate
        newItems.newAdvertisement = newAdvertisement
        newItems.seenAdvertisement = seenAdvertisement

    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    print("-----------------------------")
    print(newItems)
    return newItems
}
```

I am not knowing why all data are not getting saved in the coredata. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please write this code :->

Write `try managedObjectContext.save()` after you insert data.

```
class func createInManagedObjectContext(nameOfAdvert: String, thumbnail: String, fileName: String, videoDownloadUrl: String, subTitle: String, adType: String, mainImage: String, noOfLike: NSNumber, entryId: String, likeFlag: Bool, startDate: String, endDate: String, noOfCount: NSNumber ,clientName: String, clientImage: String, adDesc: String, sortDate: String, newAdvertisement: Bool, seenAdvertisement: Bool) -> Tube {

let managedObjectContext = DataAccess.shared.managedObjectContext

let newItems = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Tube", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Tube

    newItems.adName = nameOfAdvert
    newItems.thumbNail = thumbnail
    newItems.smilURL = fileName
    newItems.videoDownloadUrl = videoDownloadUrl
    newItems.subTitle = subTitle
    newItems.adType = adType
    newItems.mainImage = mainImage
    newItems.noOfLike = noOfLike
    newItems.entryId = entryId
    newItems.likeFlag = likeFlag
    newItems.startDate = startDate
    newItems.endDate = endDate
    newItems.noOfCount = noOfCount
    newItems.clientImage = clientImage
    newItems.clientName = clientName
    newItems.addescription = adDesc
    newItems.sortDate = sortDate
    newItems.newAdvertisement = newAdvertisement
    newItems.seenAdvertisement = seenAdvertisement

do {
    try managedObjectContext.save()
} catch let error as NSError  {
    print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
print("-----------------------------")
print(newItems)
return newItems
```

}

Comment: Thanks .. i was making this blunder mistake.I was saving data before fetching it... Thanks a lot u saved my day...